# Container Equality in Scala

Tags: scala

Basic question, I was surprised that Scala seems to support element equality in container classes. For example:

```
Seq(1,2,3)==List(1,2,3) //true
Vector(1,2,3) ==List(1,2,3) //true
```

Though as I suspected, Array does not hold up even against itself.

```
Array(1,2,3) == Array(1,2,3) //false
```

Mutable to immutable seems to work:

```
scala.collection.mutable.MutableList(1,2,3)==List(1,2,3)
```

Anyhow, what kind of assumptions can I make about this? Is this a safe way to test content equality or are there some caveats to avoid? Though this seems intuitive, I'm wondering if some issue could exist past these simple examples. What if you had a list of lists, would Scala do a deep comparison scan?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: don't trust arrays in Scala—they're usually the Java-iest thing around. If you want something that works as expected on arrays, use `xs sameElements ys`, which will force an implicit conversion to [`WrappedArray`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray).

Comment: thats great to know thank you, I was actually wondering how to do that the other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight I should have searched the term "collection equality scala" in google, because I somehow missed this answer before posting (in my searches) - but this is what I found today so I'll close this out.

*The collection libraries have a uniform approach to equality and hashing. The idea is, first, to divide collections into sets, maps, and sequences. Collections in different categories are always unequal. For instance, Set(1, 2, 3) is unequal to List(1, 2, 3)......* 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/equality.html